# Why does ContinueWith execute if I do a delay inside a task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm a little confused by what ContinueWith in the task parallel library seems to do.

My understanding is that this shouldn't be called until the task has been completed. If i'm in a while true loop this shouldn't be getting called at all.

```
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (t < DateTime.Now)  //after 10s throw
                    { 
                        throw new Exception(); //I expect it to run the continuation here
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("looped");
                    await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                }
            }
        ).ContinueWith(ct => Console.WriteLine("Continued with: {0}",ct.Result.Status)) ;
```

I would expect the following code would not run the ContinueWith method until the exception is thrown however this isn't the case. Instead I get the following output:

```
looped
Continued with: WaitingForActivation
looped
looped
looped
looped
looped
looped
looped
looped
looped
```

Why does it call ContinueWith when I hit the first delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You've created an evil `async void` delegate.</strike>

It finishes (completing the original `Task`) as soon as the synchronous part completes.
There is no way to observe the asynchronous part of the original delegate.

Your original delegate returns an asynchronous `Task` representing the async part of the operation.
However, the outer `Task` completes as soon as the synchronous part finishes, and you never wait for the inner `Task` to finish.

Instead, you should call `Task.Run()`, which accepts a `Func<Task>`.
This way, the asynchronous portions of the original delegate will contribute to the original task.

Comment: is there a better way to do this where i can still use await inside the task?

Comment: Why are you awaiting inside the task?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: Yes; use `Task.Run()`.

Comment: You can also just use `Unwrap` explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

The task that is returned from `Task.Factory.StartNew` is a `Task<Task>` because your lambda returns a `Task` and that lambda runs on the threadpool. The result of that lambda is wrapped in a `Task<T>` and put into its `Result` property.

So you need to call `Unwrap` or better use `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 0):

`ContinueWith` should be called the moment a `Task` is returned from the previous call. The `Task` is returned from the previous call before it is finished.

Edit: Actually, SLaks has identified the real problem. My statement remains true, albeit not too relevant in this instance. :)